# How to remove duplicate words or lines by comparing two text files using batch?

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I'm running a program to remove the duplicate lines by comparing two text file using batch.

This is for my personal use to make my work faster by removing duplicate lines from two text files.

**I am using the below code,**

```
copy textfile1.txt output.txt >nul
findstr /lvxig:textfile1.txt textfile2.txt >>output.txt
```

**`textfile1.txt`** contains,

```
apple
orange
mango
```

**`textfile2.txt`** contains,

```
apple
mango
grapes
```

**I expect the output in `output.txt` is,**

```
orange
grapes
```

**But the output am getting in `output.txt` is**

```
apple
orange
mango
grapes
```

*I don't want to merge two text files. I want to remove the similar duplicate by comparing those two text files.*

Answer (score 2):

What about this approach:

```cmd
findstr /LVXIG:"textfile2.txt" "textfile1.txt" > "output.txt"
findstr /LVXIG:"textfile1.txt" "textfile2.txt" >>"output.txt"
```

Or with common [redirection](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-redirection.html):

```cmd
(
    findstr /LVXIG:"textfile2.txt" "textfile1.txt"
    findstr /LVXIG:"textfile1.txt" "textfile2.txt"
) > "output.txt"
```

Using your example data, the first `findstr` command line returns:

> ```cmd
> orange
> ```

And the second one outputs:

> ```cmd
> grapes
> ```

Answer (score 0):

How about creating a hash and counting the occurrences? Then, only use those that have one (1) occurrence. This would avoid reading both files twice.

=== undupe.ps1

```
$hash = @{}
Get-Content 'testfile1.txt', 'testfile2.txt' | ForEach-Object { $hash[$_]++ }
foreach ($key in $hash.Keys) { if ($hash[$key] -eq 1) { Write-Output $key } }
```

Run it from a cmd shell or .bat file script.

```
powershell -NoLogo -NoProfile -File "undupe.ps1" >output.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
cat textfile1.txt textfile2.txt | grep -Fvxf <(comm -12 <(sort -u textfile1.txt) <(sort -u textfile2.txt))
```

explanation of this code:

cat: read data from files

comm -12 <(sort -u textfile1.txt) <(sort -u textfile2.txt): shows only duplicate lines in the two files

grep -Fvxf: remove duplicate lines resulting from comm 12

So:

textfile1.txt:

```
apple
orange
mango
```

textfile2.txt:

```
apple
mango
grapes
```

out:

```
orange
grapes
```

as the user who asked the question wants it.